# Delete files/folders from google drive using API for Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to delete a file from google drive using API for python, but the compiler returns "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

```
SCOPES1 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_secrets.json', SCOPES1)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
file_id = 'xxxx'
service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

How can I get over this issue?

Comment: Although I cannot understand about your detail situation from your question, for example, when the scope is modified from `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, what result will you get?

Comment: Sid: The file you are trying to delete, is it created using this same application, or is it created by another application/the user himself?

Comment: @carlesgg97 It is created by another application

Comment: @Tanaike I have tried both the scopes, but still the same error persists.

Comment: Sid: Can you check whether you can delete the file you are unsuccessfully attempting to remove using the API, manually? That is, head over to https://drive.google.com/open?id=<YOUR_FILE_ID> and try to remove it from the UI. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it does delete the file through the API provided on the site.

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete the file (which as far as I know is created by an application other than the one you are using) you will need the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

After that, you have to make sure that you have the valid scopes and applications defined in the [API console](https://console.developers.google.com) for your project. To do so, go to console.developers.google.com, select your project on the top dropdown, go to library and check that the drive application is enabled. Afterwards, go to "OAuth consent screen" and verify that the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is added in "Scopes for Google APIs". If it is not, make sure to add it.

After these modifications, and assuming the credentials are valid for this project, your script should be able to run.